# Why can't i create an IBOutlet in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5

I have a strange behaviour with a UITableView: i can't create IBOutlets for Controls which i have placed in a prototype cell.

On a simple ViewController i added a UITableView with two different prototype cells.
On the first prototype cell i placed some labels and a switch.
I also created a subclass from UITableViewCell and assigned this Subclass to the Prototype Cell in Interface Builder (see attached screenshot).

But here in this case I am not able to create IBOutlets for the elements in the table view cell.

I also wrote the IBOutlet in the Subclass of UITableViewCell by myself and tried to drag from the Label in the Prototype Cell to the IBOutlet and also from the Dot in the Code Window besides the IBOutlet-Declaration to the UILabel. XCode does not accept the other one.

[image: StoryBoard]

There a lots of tables and View controllers this way in the story board without any problems.

Did i missed something? Or is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

This helped:

After i repeated all steps in a temporary created new ViewController, where everything worked fine with the Outlet, i just dropped the CustomClass from the Prototype Cell in the Identity Inspector, assigned another one and returned back to the right Subclass. Then i could create the IBOutlets.